# Most efficient way to append list in loop

Tags: python, list

I am new to python.

I have the following code that request data from an API:

```
histdata = ib.reqHistoricalTicks(contracts[i],start,"",1000,'TRADES', 1, True, [])'
print(histdata)
```

The data returned is the following price information without the contract symbol:

```
[HistoricalTickLast(time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickAttribLast=TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True), price=0.95, size=1, exchange='ISE', specialConditions='f'), HistoricalTickLast(time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickAttribLast=TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True), price=0.94, size=1, exchange='ISE', specialConditions='f')]
```

First thing I would like to know is whether this type of string is a list, a list of list, a dictionary, a dataframe or something else in python?

I would like to add a "column" with the contract symbol at the start of each price row.

The data should looks like this :

| Symbol | time | tickAttribLast | price | size | exchange | specialConditions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2021-03-03 14:30:00+00:00 | TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True) | 0.95 | 1 | ISE | f |
| XYZ | 2021-03-03 14:30:00+00:00 | TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True) | 0.94 | 1 | ISE | f |

Moreover, I would like to loop through multiple contracts, get the price information, add the contract symbol and merge the contract price with the previous contract price information.

Here is my failed attempt. Could you guide me on what would be the most efficient way to add the contract symbol to each rows in histdata and then append this information in a single list or dataframe?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
i = 0

#The variable contracts is a list of contracts, here I loop the first 2 items
for t in contracts[0:1]:

print("processing contract: ", i)

#histdata get the price information of the contract (multiple price rows per contract as shown above)
histdata = ib.reqHistoricalTicks(contracts[i],start,"",1000,'TRADES', 1, True, [])

#failed attempt to add contracts[i].localSymbol at the start of each row
histdata.insert(0,contracts[i].localSymbol)

#failed attempt to append this table with the new contract information

histdata.append(histdata)

i = i + 1
```

**Edit # 1 :**

I will try and break down what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is the result of histdata :

```
[HistoricalTickLast(time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickAttribLast=TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True), price=0.95, size=1, exchange='ISE', specialConditions='f'), HistoricalTickLast(time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickAttribLast=TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True), price=0.94, size=1, exchange='ISE', specialConditions='f')]
```

What is the code needed to add the attribute "Symbol" and give this attribute the value "XYZ" to each HistoricalTickLast entries like this :

```
[HistoricalTickLast(Symbol='XYZ', time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickAttribLast=TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True), price=0.95, size=1, exchange='ISE', specialConditions='f'), HistoricalTickLast(Symbol='XYZ', time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), tickAttribLast=TickAttribLast(pastLimit=False, unreported=True), price=0.94, size=1, exchange='ISE', specialConditions='f')]
```

**EDIT #2**

I got a little confused with the map function, so I went out and transformed my LastHistoricalTicks instances to dataframe. Now, in addition to adding the attribute 'Symbol' to my first dataframe, I also merge another dataframe that contains the BID/ASK on the the key 'time'. I am sure this must be the least efficient way to do it.

Anyone wants to help me out have a more efficient code? :

```
histdf = pd.DataFrame()

print("CONTRACTS LENGTH :", len(contracts))
for t in contracts:
print("processing contract: ", i)
histdata = ib.reqHistoricalTicks(contracts[i],start,"",1000,'TRADES', 1, 
True, [])
histbidask = ib.reqHistoricalTicks(contracts[i],start,"",1000,'BID_ASK', 1, 
True, [])
tempdf = pd.DataFrame(histdata)
tempdf2 =pd.DataFrame(histbidask)
try :
    tempdf3 = pd.merge(tempdf,tempdf2, how='inner', on='time')
    tempdf3.insert(0,'localSymbol', contracts[i].localSymbol)
    histdf = pd.concat([histdf,tempdf3])
except :
    myerror["ErrorContracts"].append(format(contracts[i].localSymbol))
i = i + 1
```

Comment: `histdata` is a `list` of `HistoricalTickLast` which has attributes like `time`, `tickAttribLast` etc.

Comment: Thank you, what is the proper name of each separate row in the list (all the information separated by commas)... I'm having issue switching from VBA rows/columns type of code to python

Answer (score 0):

1. Use type() to verify that your variable is a list (indicated by the [])
2. Each entry is instances of HistoricalTickLast.  When you say you want to add a "column" that either means adding an attribute to the class, or more like that you want to process this as if it was plain old data (POD) for instance as a list of list or list of dict.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I confirm that histdata is a list : <class 'list'> What is the best way to verify variables in python without using print(type(histdata)) in the middle of my code?

Comment: In Python you typically do not write code to verify types.  Instead write your code as if it correct, then wrap the code in try except block to handle errors.  You can, of course, do `if type(variable) == type(''): ...`

Comment: For #2, I want to add an attribute to each entry of historicalTicklast. This attribute would be the contract symbol that is found with contracts[i].localSymbol. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Re #2, you have to tell us what you want (ideally by updating the question).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure histdata is a list?

If it is not a list but is an iterator, you could use list() to convert it to a list.

Also, to add an element at the begining of each interior list you could use map:

I think this code example could help you:

```
all_hisdata = []
for contract in contracts:
    histdata = list(ib.reqHistoricalTicks(
            contract,start,"",1000,'TRADES', 1, True, []))
    new_histdata = list(
        map(lambda e: [contract.localSymbol]+e, histdata)
    )
    all_hisdata.append(new_histdata)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python, maybe this is not a list. I get the following error : new_histdata = list(map(lambda e: [contracts[i].localSymbol] + e, histdata))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "HistoricalTickLast") to list

Comment: Try changing map(lambda e: [contracts[i].localSymbol] + e, histdata) with map(lambda e: [contracts[i].localSymbol] + [e], histdata) but maybe if you read about map function you could use it to achieve exactly what you want

Comment: I promise I will read more about map function. In the meantime,it seems the contract symbol was excluded from the HistoricalTickLast class. I receive : 'GLD   210305P00160000', HistoricalTickLast(time=datetime,....when I think I should be receiving HistoricalTickLast(symbol=''GLD210305P00160000',time=datetime...